# Pixelmator: I cannot open the image from Photos library that is on the external drive

Tags: external-disk, photos.app, pixelmator

My Photos Library is Inactive when I try to open an image from external drive, as it is on the image below.

[image]

What should I do to be able work with images from my Photos Library? My photos Library is located on the external disk.

Comment: Can it open images from an internal drive, inside a Library package?

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, It can open images from internal drive wherever they are. Also Pixelmator could open the images from the Photos Library until it was on the internal drive

Comment: ah, OK. Just wanted to be certain. All I can think to try right now is, Get Info on that drive, set it to Ignore ownership - that would eliminate possible permissions issues. After that, I'm really not sure

Comment: @Tetsujin, what do you mean by "ignore ownrships"? When I get Info, there is no that particular checkbox, as it is usually at the bottom, under permissions... What do you suggest?